# Declaring a variable in multipe compilation units

Tags: c

Hi everyone I have the following issue. I want to declare a variable into a .h file and to define/initialize the same variable into a .c file. Then to use the predefined variable in my main code.

This is my main:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "file.h"

int main(){
   printf("%u \n\n",i);
   system("pause");
   return 0;
}
```

this is my header file:

```
//file.h
extern unsigned int i;
```

This is my .c file:

```
//file.c
unsigned int i = 10;
```

I want my main code to print the value of 10 wich is the value of the definition in .c file. How can I link together the .c and the .h files as a multiple compilation unit?

I am using Dev-C++ ver 4.9.9.2 over windows.

Excuse my bad English

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? Doesn't it print `10`? Everything looks OK, just put them in same project or compile as `gccfile.c main.c` (replace with compiler name of your choice)

Comment: Just compile both c files and give the two object files to the linker.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an IDE ([Integrated Development Environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment)) then all the files in the project should be automatically linked together.

If you're build for hand using command line prompt, the simplest way is to list all source files on the command line, like

```
$ cc -Wall -g main.c file.c -o myprogram
```

The above command (`cc`) compiles `main.c` and `file.c` and then links them together into the resulting executable file `myprogram`.

The flags used are:

- `-Wall` to add more warnings, always good when developing
- `-g` to add debug information, that can be used by a debugger
- `-o` what to name the resulting output

Comment: @user3789035 Dev-C++ is an IDE, so as long as your files are part of the same project they should be linked together.

Answer (score 0):

Compile:

```
gcc main.c file.c -o res
```

Now with the both the `.c` files are compiled and linked together forming an executable file res

and run

```
./res
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to the other answers, it could also be good if you create a `Makefile`, your make file might have the following content

```
CC      = gcc
CFLAGS  = -Wall -Wextra -Werror
LDFLAGS =
OBJ     = main.o file.o

executable: $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJ) -o YourProgramName

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $<
```

and then, just type `make` in your console and an executable binary `YourProgramName` will be created.

If you are using an IDE, then it might be capable of opening the `Makefile` and hence load your whole project.